# Capture coordinates with location service off

Tags: android, gps

Good Morning:

Is it possible to capture the location coordinates even if the location service is off?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that defy the point of having a location service switch?

Comment: Can you please explain briefly, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to capture the GPS coordinates even if the user go to Settings and uncheck the option Location

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, no, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons.